# Accessing the /res/drawable folder in Ruboto

Tags: android, ruboto

Upon all the research I could do on the Internet, it seems as though accessing a resource (.xml layout file, in my case), located in the /res/drawable folder to return as Drawable was as simple as calling this line:

```
Ruboto::R::drawable::stroke_bg
```

However, when I tried that, I received the following error:

```
could not coerce Fixnum to class android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
```

The line on my view is:

```
scroll_view :background => Ruboto::R::drawable::stroke_bg, :layout => { :width => :match_parent, height: 1000 }
```

What is it that I am missing to get the resource out of that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ruboto::R::drawable::stroke_bg` is not a Drawable, but an `int` resource ID.  You have to get the actual resource to use it as a Drawable.  Change the background attribute to something like this:

`background: resources.getDrawable(Ruboto::R::drawable::stroke_bg)`

or

`background: resources.getDrawable($package.R.drawable.stroke_bg)`

Comment: Thanks, @donV! That makes much more sense. Worked perfectly